# How do I create an input stream from a ZipEntry

Tags: java, zip

I have a class which wraps ZipEntrys, but I'm struggling to see how I could then write a method that returns an input stream from any one ZipEntry. I managed to write something that could return an array of input streams for a ZipFile, but I need a way to get an input stream from just one ZipEntry.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233555/is-it-possible-to-get-a-zipentrys-inputstream-from-a-zipinputstream

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you not have the ZipFile instance from which the ZipEntry was sourced? If you do you could use ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipEntry).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

PS. Just had a quick look at the code and a ZipEntry is not a wrapper for the underlying data in the zip file. It is just a "place holder" for the entry as far as I can see (i.e. zipped file attributes not the data). The actual stream is created through a JNI call in the ZipFile class. Meaning that I do not believe you can do what you are looking to do in a practical way.

Comment: Malcolm, Thanks for the help, I just found that method. My problem now is that the code that originally 'opens' the zip file (when you do ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("path");), then closes it. I can stop it closing it if I want, but I was wondering - what are the consequences of not closing zips/jars? Obviously if I do remove the close() command I will leave a method so the user can close it later, but I was wondering what would happen if the user forgot - just greedy on memory?

I know it isn't a wrapper for the data - what I'm writing is a wrapper for dealing with Zip/Jar files.

Comment: Leaving it open doesn't feel like a good idea to me. Equally so for deferring responsibility for closing to the user of your solution. An option (possibly - I am guessing at the problem you are solving) is to wrap the ZipEntry and include with it a handle to the ZipFile in the wrapping class. This seems a little heavy but does mean that you can open\close a stream to the wrapped zip entry whenever you need.

Comment: What if I don't have it as a File, but I can always re-create the ZipInputStream (from a Uri, for example) ? Is it possible to have a way for each of the ZipInputStream's entries to create an InputStream, easily?

Answer (score 34):

How about this?

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("fileName.txt");       
InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
```

Comment: Unfortunately creating a new instance of ZipFile leaks file handles in 1.4.2_12

Answer (score 17):

```
 static void printInputStream(File zip) throws IOException
    {
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zip));
        for (ZipEntry zipEntry;(zipEntry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null; )
        {
            System.out.println("reading zipEntry " + zipEntry.getName());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(zin);
            while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println("reading " + zipEntry.getName() + " completed");
        }
       zin.close();
    }
```

It was found here:
[getInputStream for a ZipEntry from ZipInputStream (without using the ZipFile class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603319/getinputstream-for-a-zipentry-from-zipinputstream-with-out-using-zipfile)

Misunderstanding in what is the input stream that is opened from zip file.
Solution: open input stream from zip file
ZipInputStream `zipInputStream = ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipfile)`,
run cycle `zipInputStream.getNextEntry()`.
For every round you have the inputstream for current entry (opened for zip file before); 
..

Comment: This method is more generic than `ZipFile.getInputStream()` method since it doesn't require input coming from an actual file. So, it can be used to read an in-memory zip file content.

Comment: Don't forget to close the Scanner (`sc`).