# is it possible to get a zipentry's inputstream from a zipinputstream?

Tags: java, zip

I'm receiving a ZipInputStream from another source, and I need to provide the first entry's InputStream to another source.

I was hoping to be able to do this without saving a temp file on a device, however the only way I know of getting an InputStream for an individual entry is via ZipFile.getInputStream(entry) and since I have a ZipInputStream and not a ZipFile, that is not possible.

So the best solution I have is

1. save incoming InputStream to a file
2. read file as ZipFile
3. use first entry's InputStream
4. delete temp file.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

figured:

it's entirely possible, the call to `ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()` positions the `InputStream` at the start of the entry and therefore supplying the `ZipInputStream` is the equivalent of supplying a `ZipEntry`'s `InputStream`.

the `ZipInputStream` is smart enough to handle the entry's EOF downstream, or so it seems.

p.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by this? Can you add a sample of code?

Comment: What he means is that a ZipInputStream can be used both for the zip as a whole, and for reading each component. .getNextEntry() proceeds to first component, read it, do another .getNextEntry() and your stream is reset to the second one and so on.. Clever, actually.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to @pstanton post here is an example of code.
I solved the problem using the following code. It was difficult to understand what the previous answer without an example.

```
//If you just want the first file in the zipped InputStream use this code. 
//Otherwise loop through the InputStream using getNextEntry()
//till you find the file you want.
private InputStream convertToInputStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(stream);
    zis.getNextEntry();
    return zis;
}
```

Using this code you can return an InputStream of the file that is zipped.

Comment: And after the first component has been read, one can '.getNextEntry()' again, to read the second.

Comment: You need to close zis and then select next one. `zis.closeEntry(); zis.getNextEntry();`

Answer (score 1):

The zip code is fairly easy but I had issues with returning ZipInputStream as Inputstream. For some reason, some of the files contained within the zip had characters being dropped. The below was my solution and so far its been working.

```
private Map<String, InputStream> getFilesFromZip(final DataHandler dhZ,
        String operation) throws ServiceFault {
    Map<String, InputStream> fileEntries = new HashMap<String, InputStream>();
    try {
        ZipInputStream zipIsZ = new ZipInputStream(dhZ.getDataSource()
        .getInputStream());

        try {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipIsZ.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                    Path p = Paths.get(entry.toString());
                    fileEntries.put(p.getFileName().toString(),
                    convertZipInputStreamToInputStream(zipIsZ));
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            zipIsZ.close();
        }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        faultLocal(LOGGER, e, operation);
    }

    return fileEntries;
}
private InputStream convertZipInputStreamToInputStream(
final ZipInputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    return is;
}
```