# Parsing a zipped InputStream coming in on REST

Tags: java, json, rest, parsing, zip

In my Java backend I am receiving a json file that has been zipped.

What i have sofar is:

```
myMethod(InputStream inputStream) {

ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jsonParser = jfactory.createParser(zip);

jsonParser.nextToken();//i am expecting this to be "{" but this always returns null
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: I've never done this myself, but from looking at the API, I don't think you are using ZipInputStream correctly. You need to use getNextEntry and closeEntry instead of trying to read raw bytes off of it. Also, if possible, can you get sender to use gzip (better for this type of communication) rather than zip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to get a zipentry's inputstream from a zipinputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233555/is-it-possible-to-get-a-zipentrys-inputstream-from-a-zipinputstream)